# Removing grave accent (`) from the names of a list in R

Tags: r, naming-conventions

I have list `l` which has grave accent "`" in output. Why am I getting this in some variable and not in others?

```
l
    $`AMLM12PAH037A-B`

             Left.Gene.Symbols Right.Gene.Symbols
      PCMTD1                 0                  1
      STK31                  3                  0

    $AMLOT120AT

              Left.Gene.Symbols Right.Gene.Symbols
      ARHGEF3                 2                  0
      CD96                    2                  0
      RALYL                  12                  0
      TRIO                    0                  1
```

Comment: `-` is not valid in R as a name of an object, so it gets backticked.

Comment: @jeremycg But I have this issue with numbers without `- `as well

Comment: Yes, there are some other strange names which need the backticks. Read about *names of objects* in R

Comment: you also can't start names with a number, along with other restrictions - see `?make.names()` for a brief overview

Comment: @jogo So there must be some way to make all uniform?

Comment: See `help("make.names")`.

Comment: At least there must be a method to distinguish between an object with the name 13 and the number 13 .

Comment: @jogo tried it as.character, but no success

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have invalid names, in this case it is the `-` inside it. If you do, you will either get them backticked, like yours, converted, or an error depending on how you made them.

You also cannot start a name with a number among other restrictions.

See the functions `check.names` and `make.names`

From the [R FAQ](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#What-are-valid-names_003f):

> - A syntactic name is a string the parser interprets as this type of    expression. It consists of letters, numbers, and the dot and (for
>     versions of R at least 1.9.0) underscore characters, and starts with
>     either a letter or a dot not followed by a number. Reserved words are 
>     not syntactic names.
> - An object name is a string associated with an    object that is assigned in an expression either by having the object    name on the
>     left of an assignment operation or as an argument to the    assign()
>     function. It is usually a syntactic name as well, but can be    any
>     non-empty string if it is quoted (and it is always quoted in the
>     call to assign()).
> - An argument name is what appears to the left of    the equals sign when supplying an argument in a function call (for    example,
>     f(trim=.5)). Argument names are also usually syntactic    names, but
>     again can be anything if they are quoted.
> - An element name    is a string that identifies a piece of an object (a component of a    list, for example.) When it is used on the right
>     of the ‘$’ operator,    it must be a syntactic name, or quoted.
>     Otherwise, element names can    be any strings. (When an object is
>     used as a database, as in a call    to eval() or attach(), the element
>     names become object names.)